# Subdividing a GeoTIFF into 1x1 tiles of longitude and latitude?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, coordinates, gdal-translate

I have a big GeoTIFF file of the whole Slovakia territory in 25m resolution. It has around 17700 x 8000 pixels. I need to subdivide it into smaller files and every file must have 1° longitude and 1°latitude. I tried gdal srcwin but I don't know how many pixels is a 1° longitude and latitude and projwin didn't work for me. How do I find out how many pixels are 1° longitude and latitude?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what didn't work with `projwin`

Comment: I writed: gdal_translate -projwin_srs epsg:4326 -projwin 18.00 49.00 18.00 49.30 and of course file path. Then it report following error: "ERROR 1:Error: Computer -srcwin 4130 2202 0 -919 Has negatívne width and/or height." Probably I have entered wrong united. How I find out how units I need to enter.

Comment: 18.0 -> 18.0 is a 0 width try 18.5 (or something)

Comment: Sorry, mistake 19,0 I writed.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add the exact command you tried and what the error message was

Comment: Notice the usage: `[-projwin ulx uly lrx lry]`.

Comment: Ok, problm solved, I have wrong order of lon lat coordinates,thanks all and can I ask if there any way to expand raster layer by empty pixels? I need it for my project